# Poisson distribution questions (Find the probability that the first breakdown in June occurs on June 3rd.)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

The lifts in the office buildings of a small city have occasional breakdowns. The breakdowns at any given time are independent of one another and can be modelled using a Poisson Distribution with mean 0.2 per day.

(a) Determine the probability that there will be exactly four breakdowns during the month of June (June has 30 days).

(b) Determine the probability that there are more than 3 breakdowns during the month of June.

(c) Determine the probability that there are no breakdowns during the first five days of June.

(d) Find the probability that the first breakdown in June occurs on June 3rd.

(e) It costs 1850 Euros to service the lifts when they have breakdowns. Find the expected cost of servicing lifts for the month of June.

(f) Determine the probability that there will be no breakdowns in exactly 4 out of the first 5 days in June.

I have no idea about how to do (d). Please help me, thanks!! The answer of (d) is 0.122.Besides, I am struggling with how to identify binomial, poisson, and normal distribution form texts.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Questions that tend to get a better response are those where you can at least show your attempt and how you are thinking about it.  Usually it's good to only ask one question at a time even though a series of questions might be related.  Now you did only ask about (d) - see solution below.  Are you able to work through the others using basics of the Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of the first breakdown on June 3 is:

$Pr(\text{no breakdown on June 1})*Pr(\text{no breakdown on June 2})*Pr(\text{at least one breakdown on June 3)}$

since the events are all independent.

For the Poisson with mean $\lambda$ we have $Pr(X=k) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$ so with $\lambda=.2$ and $k=0$ we get

$e^{-.2}*e^{-.2}*(1-e^{-.2})\approx.1215$.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I just stuck at (at least one breakdown on June 3) this step. UR sooo nice!

Comment: Glad this helped.  Let me know if you are stuck on any of the others.